# cron django, task launch only by command `python manage.py cron run`

Tags: python, django, cron

I haven`t big experience with cron so want to ask you about my problem.
I have to task for cron
1.

```
def start_scraping():
    prompts = Get_search_info()

    for prompt in prompts:

        stop = False
        category = prompt.category.link if prompt.category else "oferty"
        ignore_clone = prompt.just_created

        text = prompt.text.replace(" ", "-")
        link = f"https://www.olx.pl/{category}/q-{text}/"
        response = requests.get(link).text
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

        page_number = int(page_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-testid": "pagination-list-item"})[-1].text)
        for page in range(1, page_number + 1):
            if stop:
                break
            
            pagelink = f"{link}?page={page}"
            response = requests.get(pagelink).text
            page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            cards = page_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-cy": "l-card"})
            cards_links = []

            for card in cards:
                card_url = card.find("a").get("href")
                if card_url not in cards_links and card.find(attrs={"data-testid": "adCard-featured"}) is None:
                    cards_links.append(f"https://www.olx.pl{card_url}")
                    print(card_url)

            is_exist = Add_new_link(cards_links, prompt.id)

            if is_exist and not ignore_clone:
                stop = True
        if prompt.just_created:
            change_created_status(prompt)
```

2. 

```
def start_scraping():
    prompts = Get_search_info()

    for prompt in prompts:

        stop = False
        category = prompt.category.link if prompt.category else "oferty"
        ignore_clone = prompt.just_created

        text = prompt.text.replace(" ", "-")
        link = f"https://www.olx.pl/{category}/q-{text}/"
        response = requests.get(link).text
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

        page_number = int(page_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-testid": "pagination-list-item"})[-1].text)
        for page in range(1, page_number + 1):
            if stop:
                break
            
            pagelink = f"{link}?page={page}"
            response = requests.get(pagelink).text
            page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            cards = page_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-cy": "l-card"})
            cards_links = []

            for card in cards:
                card_url = card.find("a").get("href")
                if card_url not in cards_links and card.find(attrs={"data-testid": "adCard-featured"}) is None:
                    cards_links.append(f"https://www.olx.pl{card_url}")
                    print(card_url)

            is_exist = Add_new_link(cards_links, prompt.id)

            if is_exist and not ignore_clone:
                stop = True
        if prompt.just_created:
            change_created_status(prompt)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'OlxParserApp',
    'django_crontab',
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'OlxParserApp.cron.start_scraping'), 
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'OlxParserApp.cron.Run_bot'),  # Example task schedule
      # Example task schedule
]
```

When i use command python manage.py cron run both skript are working well, but when i run server nothing gonna happend. Please help me. Ask for any additional info.

I tried really a lot,but nothing help

Comment: Did you mean `python manage.py runserver` is not working ? Well what traceback it returns ?

Comment: No, server successfully run, but Cron tasks aren`t starts with server